# Reverse each word of a string separately

Tags: php, string, reverse

How can I reverse each word of a string separately using `strrev()`?

Using `strrev()`, I'll get the following results:

Input:

```
Hello world
```

Output:

```
dlrow olleH
```

But the output should be:

```
olleH dlrow
```

How can I do this using `strrev()` or by some other method?

Comment: Suggestion, try splitting (`split()`) the string first on `' '`, then reverse and `implode()`.

Comment: @Aquillo `split` i deprecated... use `explode` or `preg_split`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$Str   = 'Hello world';
$Words = preg_split('/\s+/', $Str); // or explode(' ', $Str);

foreach ($Words as $Word)
    echo strrev($Word) . ' ';
```

output

```
olleH dlrow
```

Comment: Thanks I used yours and edited some... Thanks x999!!

$str = 'Hello world'
$Words = split(' ', $str);
        foreach ($Words as $Word)
            echo strrev($Word) . ' ';

the split() code can do already.

Comment: @Haxor: `split()` is deprecated. Use `explode()` instead.

Comment: @Haxor use `explode` or `preg_split`... `split` is deprecated!

Comment: @Haxor, nigro: Why are you using `preg_split()` for a simple split? If this is going to be used on a lot of strings, then `explode()` might be more efficient.

Comment: @AmalMurali `preg_split('/\s+/', $Str)` work with all white-space

Comment: @nigro.simone: I'm aware, but the OP hasn't said in the question that there might be newlines / tab-characters in the input string. I personally think `preg_split` is overkill for such a simple task.

Comment: @AmalMurali Is there any other code without using preg_split?

Comment: @Haxor use `explode(' ',  $Str)`

Comment: @Haxor: I already showed you how to do that in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21811914/1438393). Did you see that?

Answer (score 4):

Split, reverse, join.

```
$str = implode(' ', array_map('strrev', explode(' ', $str)));
```

[**Tada!**](https://eval.in/102139)

Comment: There is no reason to run `strtolower` and then `ucfirst`. Thus, it should be; `$pieces = array_map('strrev', explode(' ', $str))`

Comment: @RainFromHeaven: I was trying to account for words that might contain uppercase characters at different positions, but I guess that doesn't matter. Thanks!

Comment: @AmalMurali +1 for more efficient solution

Answer (score 0):

You could split the string using space (' ') as divider, and then strrev each part.